# Reflection + Linq + type casting

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, casting

I need to cast the type into the (of type) on last line

```
cbo.DataSource = DirectCast(GetType(RFOPSEntities) _
                       .GetProperty(entityName & "s") _
                       .GetGetMethod() _
                       .Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing), ObjectSet(Of ACAmp)))
                       .OrderBy(Function(c As ACAmp)) c.SortOrder).ToList()
```

Now I need to do semeting like that:

```
cbo.DataSource = DirectCast(GetType(RFOPSEntities) _
                            .GetProperty(entityName & "s") _
                            .GetGetMethod() _
                            .Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing), ObjectSet(Of Type.GetType("ACAmp"))).OrderBy(Function(c As Type.GetType("ACAmp")) c.SortOrder).ToList()
```

The Type.GetType("ACAmp") is not goog but the type could be pass by string. How ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to replace the (Of ACAmp) with something like (Of GetType("ACAmp"))

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Generic parameters - `(Of XYZ)` - need to be known at compile time, but `GetType("ACAmp")` is executed at runtime.

Comment: It probably isn't the answer to the real problem so I won't put this as an answer, but you _can_ use Reflection to generate actual types from Generic Types and Types only known at run time.